# Default host name for an IP address

Tags: dns, ip, host, same-origin-policy

If an IP address doesn't have a hostname set in the `hosts` file, and it also doesn't have a binding domain name, then what is its hostname, the IP address itself? Since [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) asks for the same `host`, not for the same IP, so it must have a hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access from the same machine it can be accessed via:

1. localhost
2. 127.0.0.1
3. 0.0.0.0

P.S. If you are on a different machine and no domain is mapped to the IP address, then IP address itself will be the host name until a domain is explicitly mapped to it. You might have to do some additional setup depending on your use case to make it remotely accessible.

Comment: _If you are on a different machine and no domain is mapped to the IP address, then IP address itself will be the host name until a domain is explicitly mapped to it._

Any reference to this?

Comment: It depends upon what and how are you trying to do such as if:
> It is an API server (if yes, what is the programming language nodejs, php, etc)
> It is on linux or windows environment (as both have hosts file configuration).

It would be helpful if you can elaborate your use case a bit. Thanks.

Comment: It's a website, say it's IP is `220.181.38.149`, it doesn't have a domain name or host name configured in `hosts` file, I wonder what host name it has, since [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) checks host name, not IP.

Comment: If there is no domain assigned, the IP address is considered as the host name only.

Comment: You can confirm the same if you visit the  ip `220.181.38.149` in your browser, open the Developer console and type `window.location` or `document.domain` you will get the host name and domain values as `220.181.38.149` (IP address) only.

Comment: Thanks, I think you meant `location.hostname`?

Comment: Yes you can do that too for getting the value directly instead of the entire location object.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` means any address, it does not mean local one.